# Factory Girl with legacy read only database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot, legacy, monkeypatching

I am setting up tests for an application that links to a read only legacy database.

I have 2 models ProductSpecification and Stock. The Stock model is accessing read only data on a legacy database.

```
class ProductSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :stock
  validates :stock_id, uniqueness: true, presence: true

  def stock_name
    stock.name
  end
end

class Stock < ActiveRecord::Base
  def readonly?
    @readonly = true
  end
end
```

I need to set up the factory with a stock name but adding a stock_name writer method in ProductSpecification violates the fact that Stock is readonly.

To get around this I have monkey patched the ProductSpecification in the factory file.

```
class ProductSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
  def stock_name= name
    # the stock table is read only to a legacy database
    # this monkey patch allows a stock name to be set without adding stock
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product_specification do
    sequence(:stock_id)
    sequence(:stock_name){ |n| "Stock Name #{n}" }
  end
end
```

This allows me to set a stock_name purely for the tests.

Is there a better practice to follow here?
Is there an alternative solution to the monkey patch I haven't considered?

Answer (score 0):

I would try `attr_readonly :important_type_thingie` in the model

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I think this only works if the `:important_type_thingie` is a column in the database of the model.